# Group or eliminate duplicates fields in columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to group the data of the field 1 that has more data in the field 2

```
+-----+----------+---------------+
| id  |  field1  |    field2     |
+-----+----------+---------------+
|  1  |   ONE    |   Medicine    |
|  2  |   TWO    |   Food        |
|  3  |   TWO    |   Medicine    |
+-----+----------+---------------+
```

I want something like this

```
+-----+----------+---------------+
| id  |  field1  |    field2     |
+-----+----------+---------------+
|  1  |   ONE    |   Medicine    |
|  2  |   TWO    |   Food        |
|  3  |          |   Medicine    |
+-----+----------+---------------+
```

I dont know if is possible im new in mysql

thanks for your time

Comment: What is your mysql version? MySQL 8.0 or older?

Comment: Im currently using mysql 8.0

Answer (score 2):

You can use case when first record of group display the value, otherwise empty string:

```
SELECT ID, 
  CASE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY field1) WHEN 1 THEN field1 ELSE "" END AS FIELD1, 
  field2  
FROM table
;
```

Comment: I use with mysql version 8.0.15

Answer (score 0):

This technique should work for any version

```
SELECT (
    CASE WHEN (
             SELECT count(b.f1) 
                FROM tbl b 
                WHERE b.f1 = a.f1 AND a.id > b.id) > 0 
             THEN '' ELSE a.f1 END) f1, a.f2 
       FROM tbl a 
ORDER BY a.f1, a.id asc;
```